# React iterate json api to setState variable

Tags: reactjs

I have this `useState`:

```
const [records, setRecords] = useState([
    { title: "", date: ''}
    ]);
```

in this `useState` I'm try to iterate my api record:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/events')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        data.map((item) => (
          setRecords({title: item.name, date: item.starts_at })
        ))

      })
  }, console.log(records))
```

im trying to put my API records to my setRecords and end up to infinite loop.

im newbie in React

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed the scopes. `setRecords` should be called only once, with the entire new records array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/events')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      const newData = data.map((item) => (
        { title: item.name, date: item.starts_at }
      ));
      setRecords(newData);
    })
}, []) // This is the dependency array. Not sure why there was a console.log there
```

Comment: bro its working but i cant accept the answer in 4 mins

Comment: bro can you add your answer how about when i use axios? what is the syntax of the useEffect?